# Negation in Apache IndexIgnore

Tags: regex, apache, apache-config

I need a IndexIgnore rule in apache, that only allows fx. .gif files to be shown...

So this is the "pseudo" code:

```
IndexIgnore !*.gif
```

How would i do this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you provide some input and expected output ?

Comment: What im trying is to only list .gif files in file index generated by apache.
And you can use IndexIgnore to ignore files from list, so i guess it might be possible to ignore all files, Except some filetype?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this by IndexIgnore.
It's a wildcard expression, not a regex.

```
File is a shell-style wildcard expression or full filename.
```